# figtext datetime function matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to create a text box within my graph in matplotlib where it gives me the date in which the graph was created.

I have created a text box in the bottom right corner of my graph using the figtext function in matplotlib, but cannot figure out how to incorporate the python datetime function within the text box so it displays the date. Any ideas?

Code and graph below:

```
#Stacked Bar Char- matplotlib
#Create the general blog and the "subplots" i.e. the bars
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,5), dpi=1000)
# Set the bar width
bar_width = 0.50
# positions of the left bar-boundaries
bar_l = [i+1 for i in range(len(df4['Pandas']))] 
# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i+(bar_width/2) for i in bar_l] 

#Stack the negative bars by region
#Start bottom at 0, and then use pandas to add bars together
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats1'], width=bar_width, label='cats',color='R', alpha=.4, align='center', 
        bottom = 0)
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['dogs1'], width=bar_width,label='dogs',color='#ADD8E6',alpha=.4, fill=True, align='center',
        bottom =(df4['cats1']))
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['zebras1'], width=bar_width, label='zebras',color='#FFA500',alpha=.4, align='center',
        bottom = np.array(df4['cats1'])+np.array(df4['dogs1']))
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['pandas1'], width=bar_width, label='pandas', color='b',alpha=.5, fill=True, align='center',
        bottom = np.array(df4['cats1'])+np.array(df4['dogs1'])+np.array(df4['zebras1']))
#Stack the positive bars by region
#Start bottom at 0, and then use pandas to add bars together
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats'], width=bar_width,color='R', alpha=.4, align='center', 
        bottom = 0)
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['dogs'], width=bar_width,color='#ADD8E6',alpha=.4, fill=True, align='center',
        bottom =(df4['cats']))
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['zebras'], width=bar_width ,color='#FFA500',alpha=.4, align='center',
        bottom = np.array(df4['cats'])+np.array(df4['dogs']))
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['pandas'], width=bar_width, color='b',alpha=.5, fill=True, align='center',
        bottom = np.array(df4['cats'])+np.array(df4['dogs'])+np.array(df4['zebras']))

# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, df4['Year'],fontsize=10)


# Set the label and legends
plt.title('Animals on the farm', fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylim([-1600,1000])
ax1.set_ylabel("Count",fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlabel("Year",fontsize=12)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size':6})
ax1.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax1.axvline(x=0, color='k')
plt.figtext(0, 0,"Data as of ", wrap=False,
            horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment ='bottom', fontsize=8)
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), rotation='horizontal', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[Graph= Animals on the Farm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7BqI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with today's date:

```
import datetime as dt

plt.figtext(0, 0,"Data as of {}".format(dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), wrap=False,
            horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment ='bottom', fontsize=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `datetime` object, you can use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method to convert it to a string representation using the formatting you want:

```
from datetime import datetime
plt.figtext(0, 0, 'Date as of ' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Thank you both! This was super helpful.